# How do I write XSLT for an xml containing a list

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml which looks like this:

```
<Person>
 <Details>
  <AddressDetails>
   <Address>
    <street>3</street>
   </Address>
   <Address>
    <street>4</street>
   </Address>
   <Address>
    <street>5</street>
   </Address>
  </AddressDetails>
 </Details>
</Person>
```

I want to convert this xml into something like this:

```
<Person>
 <Details>
  <AddressDetails>
   <Address>
    <Class>List</Class>
     <Results "REPEATINGTYPE= LIST">
      <Data>
       Contains all the data that is present in the dynamic address list.
      </Data>
      <Data>
      </Data>
     </Results>
   </Address>
   </AddressDetails>
  </Details>
</Person>
```

The XSL Template that i am writing is:

```
<xsl:template match="/Person">
<Person>
<Details>
<AddressDetails>
<Address>
<Class>List</Class>
<Results REPEATINGTYPE= "LIST">
<xsl:for-each select="Address">
<Data>
<Street><xsl:value-of select="Street" /></Street>
</Data>
</Results>
</Address>
</AddressDetails>
</Details>
</Person>
</xsl:template>
```

But it is not picking up the list elements. Can someone help with this ?

**EDIT:**

The Output that i am getting is:

```
<Person>
    <Details>
    <AddressDetails>
    <Address>
    <Class>List</Class>
    </Address>
    </AddressDetails>
    </Details>
</Person>
```

Comment: what is your ouput or any error?

Comment: Please post the **exact** code you expect to get as the output.

Comment: Let me reframe the question

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Reframed. Please check now

Comment: And where is your XSLT?

Comment: @Chandeep I have rolled back your question to what it was when I answered it. If you have a different question (or questions, since you have already changed this one twice, to two wildly different questions), please start a new question for each.

Answer (score 0):

The XSL you have posted is invalid: you have no closing tag for `xsl-for-each`.

In addition, `<xsl:for-each select="Address">` does not select anything from the context of `Person`; you need to change it to `<xsl:for-each select="Details/AddressDetails/Address">`.

Finally, XML is case-sensitive: `<xsl:value-of select="Street" />` will not return anything when the source element is named `street`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to wrap all `<Values>` inside a `<Response>` in `<AllResults><data>`?

Use a template for `<Response>` and an identity transform for everything else, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:p="http://www.w3org.com"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" priority="0">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p:Response" priority="10">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()!='Values'] | @*"/>
            <p:AllResults REPEATINGTYPE="List">
                <p:data>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="p:Values"/>
                </p:data>
            </p:AllResults>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the quesiton that I just [posted?

Comment: This is a completely different question. If you want to ask a different question, you should create a new, not edit the previous one. Anyway, the problem with your new xslt is that you don't specify namespace for each match or select.